# Chrome browser font problem after update in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, google-chrome, chromium

I installed Xubuntu 14.04 and when I downloaded and installed Google Chrome after updating the database Chrome displays fonts like this:

[image: scrambled font on chrome]

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Ask Ubuntu community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the font you were using was deleted during an update.

Could you try setting *deja vu sans* as the font in Chrome Settings and see the result?